# Why some circuits do not work

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why some circuits which are made by professional does not work but theoretically
they are correct i tried to make circuits of some well known web sits but all of 
them were just crap and wast of time and money why these Diy magazines publish
such circuits which are just misleading and bullshit Do they not check their circuit
before publishing in there magazines and websites is there any way to test the circuit
before making it i know that you would suggest me simulating them in any simulation 
software but there are some circuit which i do not think that they can be simulated
 in any software for example a FM transmitter circuit or a clap clap switch circuit
because such circuits need a sound source to work and  when i will simulate them
in a software how will i arrange a sound source for a clap switch or a FM transmitter
circuit to test them whether they are working or not plz guide me somebody.
thank you

Comment: Where is the question? All I see is pointless ranting

Comment: what makes you think that most of the circuits you find for free on the internet are not just horrible hack jobs?

Comment: so you tried to build an FM transmitter and it didn't work on the first try? I'd be surprised if the opposite happened.

Answer (score 4):

All circuits work in some way, whether or not their operation meets your spec is the question. If you're building circuits from the internet and magazines without understanding **how** they work, yeah, you're going to fail. Instead of ranting about it, pick one of this "crap" circuits, learn how it works, and if your implementation doesn't work, learn to fix it.